# get numeric value from string jquery

Tags: jquery

I am showing prices in span class want to add all the prices.To do that I have to remove the currency(which is dynamic).

data will be

```
<div class="js-price-cell">
  <span class="js-price">$280.00</span>
</div>
<div class="js-price-cell">
  <span class="js-price">$280.00</span>
</div>
```

I tried with

```
$form.find('.js-price-cell').each(function () {
  let priceText= $(this).find('.js-price').text();
  var itemTotal= parseFloat(priceText.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''));
  totalAmt += itemTotal;
});
```

Instead of 560.00. It is giving as 56000. Seems like even the `.` is getting replaced.

Comment: and what is the problem? Just calculate in cent and add the point when outputting

Comment: you can replace only the $ sign `priceText.replace('$', '')`

Comment: Store the price in a `data-` attribute and use that instead of parsing text.

Comment: priceText.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '') is returning 28000. I want it as 280.00 .

Comment: If the *"currency is dynamic"* (assuming eg $/£ etc) then the number format will also be dynamic as some cultures use `,` (comma) for decimal places.   Better to separate the display from the data.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, currency is dynamic.It can be anything

Comment: so why do you ignore my solution?

Comment: @sree so you can use `priceText.substring(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replaced the priceText: all non-decimals are removed. Add a . to the regex and it should work.

```
var itemTotal= parseFloat(priceText.replace(/[^0-9\.]/gi, ''));
```

Comment: and then he will have something like €20.000,53 which is common in Germany. Removing all non decimals is perfect. Then you can calculate with integer as cents

Comment: Well, it is not up to us what he might expect and what not. I am simply answering his question.